# Is it possible to use git for tracking changes without storing them?

Tags: git, binaryfiles

I have a big directory structure with lots of binary files (images) in it. I want to track which files were added/deleted/changed without actually storing the changes.
Is it possible to do using git?

Just to reiterate, I don't care about the contents of the change, just want to register the fact that the file was added/deleted/changed.

Open to other suggestions besides git that work across Windows/Linux/macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @eftshift0 advice this is what I'm doing now (and it works well!)

1. Exclude everything except my directory listing with .gitignore

   ```
    *
    !.gitignore
    !ls.txt
   ```
2. Save list of files with modified dates into ls.txt (decided using date to track changes is enough for me for now, so not doing the checksum).

   ```
    find . -printf "%c %p\n" -iname "*.mov" -o -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.mp4" > ls.txt
   ```
3. Commit the listing

   ```
    git add ls.txt
    git commit -m "added some files"
   ```

PS Printing time with find actually can be quite slow (takes several minutes with my directory of about 10k files), so if you are tracking many files and you don't care about the modified date, better take it out.
Could be just windows thing though (i'm using git bash on windows).

Answer (score 3):

No. That is not, in fact, what Git is. It doesn't even *know* that any files were added/deleted/changed. It just takes snapshots of your actual project. Every snapshot contains all the files in the project. That is all that Git actually stores. You can't ask it *not* to do that; that's what Git does, period.

Comment: This is not correct. It's what the standard workflow does, but building a Git workfow to track just the hash codes for specific files, no content, is not too hard. `git update-index --add --cache-info 100644,$(git hash-object $path),$path`, `git write-tree --missing-ok`, `git commit-tree` are the starting points.

Comment: Thaks for the idea @jthill ! What should I put into $path? Something like "*.jpg" and then repeat for other extensions?

Comment: No, for bulk work you'll want to construct index entries in bulk and feed them in through [the `--index-info` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_index_info). Git does provide the wiring and the parts to construct pretty much any pushbutton you want, but you're going to have to construct it, which means either a long conversation about exactly what you want or becoming one yourself. It's really not that hard, Git is quite simple underneath, but it does mean losing any fascination with abstraction and not being able to use the familiar commands.

Comment: I'm sorry but the more I hear about this project the more I'm convinced that Git is totally the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Gotta say I tend to agree there for any team that isn't already comfortable with Git.

Answer (score 1):

You could.... with some magic tricks outside of git, actually. Generate a list of all present files (with their checksums, be it sha1 or sha256 or md5) and put them in a file... add the file, commit.... then, after a while you do the same.... add, commit..... then after a while you do the same. So..... you could, by comparing the contents of **that single file** over different commits, know what happened, without actually storing the images themselves. Not too elegant, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great Idea! I'll post a detailed answer that work for me :)